# QueryDSL order by relation is null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to order a querydsl query so that all entities with a null value for a relationship are ordered first, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I would expect:

```
query.orderBy(
  QBook.book.original.isNull().asc()
)
```

To be what I need, where `original` is a self-referential relationship with `Book`.

But that produces the exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: is null 
[select book
from com.mydomain.Book book 
order by book.original is null asc]
```

(The real exception is much longer, but that should be all the relevant info.)

I've also tried

```
QBook.book.original.name.asc().nullsFirst()
```

But that has two problems. First, it eliminates all books without an `original`, and even if it didn't, it would sort them based off name, when I only want them sorted off of whether that value is null.

Hibernate version: 3.6.6.Final

QueryDSL version: 3.2.3

Comment: Thanks to [this bug fix](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/582) it looks like with query dsl 3.3.0 or higher `QBook.book.original.name.asc().nullsFirst()` would at least include null values thanks to left joins.

Comment: Have you tried it with a newer version of Querydsl?

Comment: It wouldn't be practical to try upgrading Querydsl right now, but hopefully we'll be able to upgrade it in the not-too-distant future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lacking a better solution, I plan to add a boolean value indicating whether or not `original` is null. That value can easily be ordered by in the way I want.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the CaseBuilder:

```
query.orderBy(new CaseBuilder()
     .when(QBook.book.original.isNull())
     .then(0)
     .otherwise(1)
     .asc()
)
```